# How to use redirect_to like method in stimulus reflex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to learn stimulus reflex. Working on a basic project management app where I am trying to redirect_to some path from controller. How can I do this using stimulus reflex

Comment: As I replied this pattern is not really supported, but maybe if you share your use case, we can recommend you a good pattern for that. Such a question is however better suited for the stimulus reflex discord than for SO: https://cableready.stimulusreflex.com/reference/operations/event-dispatch#dispatch_event

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Stimulus Reflex is there to call a remote procedure and rerender the page / or a part of it, with the new state. If you are going to do a redirect after a successful action then you would go for a classic controller action.

It would be possible to emit an event from a reflex with [cable ready](https://cableready.stimulusreflex.com/reference/operations/event-dispatch#dispatch_event) and listen to that event on a custom stimulus controller to then "redirect" to another page, but that does not make things easier.